# Show lower and upper bounds in geom_bin histogram (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, plotly, ggplotly

In the following histogram, how can I include the lower and upper bounds *for each bin* as tooltip text in ggplotly?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
csub<-data.frame(Anomaly10y = rpois(50,5))
p <-  ggplot(csub,aes(x=Anomaly10y)) + 
  stat_bin(binwidth=1, aes(label1 = min(Anomaly10y, na.rm = T), label2 = 
  max(Anomaly10y, na.rm = T))) 
ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("label1", "label2"))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution, but you can trick it, using `geom_bar()` to get what you want. Here is an alternative:

```
#first extract the data from stat_bin
p <-  ggplot(csub,aes(x=Anomaly10y)) + stat_bin(binwidth=1) 

temp <- layer_data(p, 1)
#ggplot
pp <- ggplot(data = temp, aes(x =x,y=y, label1 = xmin, label2 = xmax)) + 
geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = "darkgrey", width = 1)
```

and then plot with `ggplotly`:

```
ggplotly(pp)
```

or

```
ggplotly(pp, tooltip = c("label1", "label2"))
```

Maybe someone as solution with this option, but:

```
pp <-  ggplot(csub,aes(x=Anomaly10y)) + 
    stat_bin(binwidth=1)  + 
stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom="text", aes(label=..xmin..), vjust = 2)  + 
stat_bin(binwidth=1, geom="text", aes(label=..xmax..)) 
ggplotly(pp)
```

I get only one of the label, not both.